# Oracle - How to know the load volume by times of a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, datatable

I have some tables in Oracle and I would like to know the variations of the table by sections of time.

I explain, I need a query/script to know how often data is loaded / updated in the table.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZQiW.png)

Can anyone give me ideas on how to do something like that or similar?
Thanks!

Comment: Check pl/sql triggers https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS750 I think you can achieve this by using them

Comment: Read about dba_tab_modifications in documentation.

Comment: Triggers? I think not, but I might be wrong. Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: `dba_tab_modifications`? Aha, that's how you read the equestion, @DrYWit. May be, can't tell ... I understood it quite different (as my answer below shows). We'll see what the OP says.

Comment: I would need a mix between @DrYWit and Littlefoot ´s answers.
My main problem is that I don't have any field in the table that reflects the date of insertion / modification of the record and I suppose I would need to use dba_tab_modifications.

Comment: My scenario has changed.
Now I could use the replicated tables in a Teradata environment, with a Timestamp field and a field that tells me if it's insert or update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split a day to hours (CTEs `times` and `periods`) and apply aggregates to values stored in `your_table` (which is joined to "fabricated" hours). For example:

```
SQL> with times as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/24 val
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 25
  5    ),
  6  periods as
  7    (select val val_from,
  8            lead(val) over (order by val) val_to
  9     from times
 10    ),
 11  your_table (date_column, ins, upd) as
 12    (select trunc(sysdate) + 13/24 + 25/(24*60),  100, 18    from dual union all
 13     select trunc(sysdate) + 13/24 + 25/(24*60),  225, null  from dual union all
 14     select trunc(sysdate) + 14/24 + 33/(24*60),  203, 112   from dual union all
 15     select trunc(sysdate) + 15/24 + 15/(24*60), null, 687   from dual union all
 16     select trunc(sysdate) + 15/24 + 18/(24*60), null, 987   from dual
 17    )
 18  select to_char(p.val_from, 'hh24:mi') ||' - '||
 19         to_char(p.val_to  , 'hh24:mi') period,
 20         count(ins) cnt_insert,
 21         count(upd) cnt_update
 22  from periods p join your_table t on t.date_column >= p.val_from
 23                                  and t.date_column < p.val_to
 24  where p.val_to is not null
 25  group by p.val_from, p.val_to
 26  order by p.val_From;

PERIOD        CNT_INSERT CNT_UPDATE
------------- ---------- ----------
13:00 - 14:00          2          1
14:00 - 15:00          1          1
15:00 - 16:00          0          2

SQL>
```